# Best approach for sending daily email reminders

Tags: apex, email, batch, scheduled-apex

I use scheduler + batch apex + Messaging.SingleEmailMessage to send out reminder emails every 2 weeks to a specific set of users in a public group!!!

Is this a decent approach/ is there any other alternative approach that I can do using time based workflow which I can take?

Comment: Are these reminders for tasks that haven't been completed?

Comment: Nope the reminders are intended to just remind them that they need to fill out some fields, the template is very general template that says "Please go to the account ABC and update the fields pending for the week 1) name 2) contactinfo "

Comment: Do you have some sort of rules that define when a user needs to update these fields? I'm sure you could do something with a time based workflow.

Comment: Time based ones fire only once if I recall correctly. This sounds like a periodic task so I'd go with batch apex as well. Recently we got option to assign tasks to groups but the reminder there is also one-time I think. Can you simply mass create (recurring) Events in calendars?

Comment: I want something simple!!! The current scheduler is doing the job perfectly as expected. Was just curious to know if there was a simpler approach!!! @eyescream creating mass events would affect another part of the team where a email gets triggered based on event creation so not an option

Comment: @DanielHoechst I have a request when the user has not updated a particular field for more than 2 weeks I need to trigger the email !!! I believe that there is no way to trigger the workflow of the history objects, so I create a notifier and force a update manually !!! Is there a better approach ?

Comment: @DanielHoechst I take back my earlier comment !!! I just found I can check if a field has changed as a part of the workflow formula criteria and trigger an email!!!

Comment: Yes, but the ISCHANGED function only works when a record is created, and every time it’s edited. The problem is that this type of workflow rule doesn't support time-dependent actions, so the email would get sent immediately instead of waiting the two weeks.

Comment: Dang!!!Does this mean I  am struck then with switching on field history tracking and sending email off the history object :(!!! Is there a better approach than this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you require a proactive scan, Scheduled Apex would be the recommended approach.

You could have a hidden `Date` field on `Account` called `FieldsLastUpdated__c`

Have a workflow that fires each time the record is created or edited, check if the fields you're interested in are updated (using `ISCHANGED()`) and if they have been updated, set this date to `TODAY()`

This now signifies that those fields were updated on the Date stamped in the `FieldsLastUpdated_c`

Have a simple batch class that runs each night, and scans for Account records `where FieldsLastUpdated__c < Date.today().addDays(-14)` i.e. 2 weeks using the QueryLocator

Now in your execute cycle through these Account and for each create an email for the owner, and the finally bulk send.